# Xamarin Forms - JSON - Getting Nested Values

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin.forms, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for the basic question, please don't flame me.

But how do I get a nested value form a JSON package? I was able to get the first field but the nested values baffle me.

Here's the json response:

```
{
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "result" : {
       "address_components" : [
          {
             "long_name" : "27",
             "short_name" : "27",
             "types" : [ "street_number" ]
          },
       ]
       "formatted_address" : "xxxxx",
       "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
       "name" : "27 Percy St",
       "place_id" : "xxxxx",
       "reference" : "xxxxx",
       "types" : [ "premise" ],
       "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=xxxxx&ftid=0x6b12bc036a9c581d:0x661b35b7a051a51",
       "utc_offset" : 600,
       "vicinity" : "xxxx"
    },
    "status" : "OK"
```

I want to get the formatted_address but I can only seem to get the status part.

Here's my code:

```
string GooglePlaceAPIKey = "xxxx";
string SelectedPlaceID = googleplace.PlaceID;
string GooglePlaceDetailAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=" + GooglePlaceAPIKey + "&place_id=" + SelectedPlaceID;
Console.WriteLine(GooglePlaceDetailAPI);
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = GooglePlaceDetailAPI;
var response_status = await client.GetAsync(uri);
var response_package = await response_status.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Root results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response_package);
Console.WriteLine(results.status);
```

And here's my class:

```
public class Root
        {
            public List<Prediction> predictions { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            // Google Places Details
            public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
            public Result results { get; set; }
        }

public class Result
        {
            public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
            public string formatted_address { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string place_id { get; set; }
            public string reference { get; set; }
            public List<string> types { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int utc_offset { get; set; }
            public string vicinity { get; set; }
        }
```

I also tried changing the deserialiser to another class so I can pull out the formatted_address but no values seem to be stored in that variable.

```
Result results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(response_package);
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is basically correct, you just need to get the `address_components` from the `Root` object again.

```
Root results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root >(response_package);
var address_components = results.result.address_components;
```

the model:

```
public class Root 
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    // Google Places Details
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; } //notice here you should use "result" the same as the key in your json string.

}
public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }    
}
public class AddressComponent
{

    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}
```